# what happen when you run client without server running?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, wireshark, tcpclient

I got an interview question in sockets in c programming
I got two files server.c and client.c

I was asked what will happen if you run a client when the server is not running : more specifically

> run `./client localhost` without running `./server` in a different terminal

and I didn't know the answer (obviously it won't connect but what will happen I don't know)
they wanted an answer that was related to the sockets

when I checked in Wireshark to see if I can get some information I saw this:
[image: the focus on the red record of the TCP sockets]

the focus on the red record of the TCP sockets and the one record above it.

9999 is the port of the server
what is the meaning of every parameter here?

> 56020 ->9999 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65495 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=736093598 TSecr=0 WS=128

and also what is the meaning of

> 9999 -> 56020 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0

I tried to look for the meaning in google but didn't find results that related to sockets.
thank you very much in advanced!

code for the client.c

```
// to run in the terminal compile with 
// gcc -o client client.c -Wall  
// then run the following command:
// ./client localhost

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define SIM_LENGTH 10
// #define IP_ADDRESS "127.0.0.1" // from the last part we put this in comment and resolve it with gethostbyname
#define PORT 9999

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sock;
  struct sockaddr_in cli_name;
  int count;
  int value;
  char *hostname;
  char *hostaddr;
  struct addrinfo *res;
  struct sockaddr_in *saddr;
  printf("Client is alive and establishing socket connection.\n");
  printf("%d  %s\n", argc, argv[1]);
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    perror("Usage: hostnamelookup <hostname> error \n");
    exit(1);
  }

  hostname = argv[1]; // hostname is the first argument
  printf("Hostname is %s\n", hostname);

  if (0 != getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, NULL, &res)) // getaddrinfo is a function that returns a struct addrinfo* that
  // contains a linked list of struct addrinfo (from nslookup.c)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in resolving hostname %s\n", hostname);
    exit(1);
  }

  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
  {
    perror("Error opening channel");
    close(sock);
    exit(1);
  }

  saddr = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr; // get the address of the server socket address structure (from nslookup.c)
  hostaddr = inet_ntoa(saddr->sin_addr);      // get the IP address of the server (from nslookup.c)

  bzero(&cli_name, sizeof(cli_name));
  cli_name.sin_family = AF_INET;
  cli_name.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostaddr); // set the IP address of the client (from nslookup.c)
  cli_name.sin_port = htons(PORT);

  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_name, sizeof(cli_name)) < 0)
  {
    perror("Error establishing communications");
    close(sock);
    exit(1);
  }

  for (count = 1; count <= SIM_LENGTH; count++)
  {
    read(sock, &value, 4);
    printf("Client has received %d from socket.\n", value);
  }

  printf("Exiting now.\n");

  close(sock);
  exit(0);
}
```

server.c

```
// to run in the terminal compile with 
// gcc -o server server.c -Wall  
// then run the following command:
// ./server 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#define SIM_LENGTH 10
#define PORT 9999

int main(void)
{
  int sock;                     // socket descriptor
  int connect_sock;             // socket descriptor for the connection
  struct sockaddr_in serv_name; // server socket address structure
  socklen_t len;                // length of the socket address structure
  int count;                    // number of bytes received

  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // create a socket
                                          // check if the socket is valid
  if (sock < 0)
  {
    perror("Error opening channel");
    exit(1);
  }
  // initialize the server socket address structure
  bzero(&serv_name, sizeof(serv_name)); // clear the structure
  serv_name.sin_family = AF_INET;       // set the family to Internet
  serv_name.sin_port = htons(PORT);     // set the port number

  // check if the bind is successful
  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_name, sizeof(serv_name)) < 0) // bind the socket to the server address
  {
    perror("Error on binding");
    exit(1);
  }

  // listen for connections
  if (listen(sock, 1) < 0) // listen for connections on the socket
  {
    perror("Error on listening");
    exit(1);
  }

  len = sizeof(serv_name); // get the length of the socket address structure

  connect_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_name, &len); // accept a connection on the socket
                                                                    // check if the connection is valid
  if (connect_sock < 0)
  {
    perror("Error on accepting");
    exit(1);
  }
  for (count = 1; count <= SIM_LENGTH; count++) // loop to send the data
  {
    write(connect_sock, &count, 4);                      // send the data
    printf("Server has written %d to socket.\n", count); // print the data
  }

  close(connect_sock); // close the connection
  close(sock);         // close the socket
}
```

Comment: "Server is not working" is too broad to be able to give a single precise answer. Not working *how*? Is the program running but not accepting connections? Not running? Server machine not up or a network cable unplugged? Router in between down? All of these will give different errors back.

Comment: the code of the server is not running in a different terminal this is what i meant

Comment: Broken anyway, for two of the usual three reasons: failure to correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls like recv() and failure to understand the octet-streaming of TCP.

Comment: what do you mean by "broken anyway" and failure to "and failure to understand the octet-streaming of TCP. " can you explain what i fail to understand please or give me a link to know more

Comment: Side note: the first code fragment lists a lot of headers twice.  At one level, no harm is done, but it looks weird and incompetent.

Comment: Note 'SOCK_STREAM':).  It's a stream of bytes.  Just because you ask for four bytes to be read, [read(sock, &value, 4);], does not mean that a sucessful read willl get you 4.  You may get 1,2,3 or 4 bytes read into 'value'.  The ONLY way to know, for sure, how many bytes were loaded is to handle the value returned by the read() call, (which you ignore).  Unfortunately, with a good link etc. this issue will likely show up very intermittently and result in, very occasional, catastrophic data transfers:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the host on that IP is completely down and unreachable (or the destination port is effectively firewalled), then the client will retry initiating the three way handshake a few times before timing out and bubbling up an error to the socket application calling `connect`.

If the host is up, but not listening on the expected port, it will send back an `RST` in response to receiving `SYN` from the client.  That will effectively tell the client to "go away, I'm not listening". And the TCP stack will again bubble up an error to the socket application to trigger its `connect` call to return an error.

Comment: can you explain but why i see 9999 -> 56020 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0 in the info of wireshark ?

Comment: where does 56020 come from ?

Comment: @MayaCohen every peer in a TCP connection has an IP and port assigned to it. In your case, 56020 was an available ephemeral port that `connect()` randomly choose for the local peer when starting the outgoing connection.

Comment: can you also explain ```[RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0``` where i can get more information about the meaning of these word? and these ```[SYN] Seq=0 Win=65495 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=736093598 TSecr=0 WS=128``` please

Comment: @MayaCohen - https://www.amazon.com/TCP-Illustrated-Protocols-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0321336313/